# You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, redux-form

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import  createHistory  from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import  ConnectedRouter  from 'react-router-redux';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router';
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Register from "./pages/Register";
import CourseManagerDashboard from "./pages/CourseManagerDashboard";
import CourseDetail from "./pages/CourseDetail";
import App from './app/App';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';

const store = createStore(
    state => state
);
const history = createHistory();

ReactDOM.render((
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <Switch>
                <Route name="home" exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route name="register" path="/register" component={Register} />
                <Route name="course-manager-dashboard" path="/course-manager-dashboard" component={CourseManagerDashboard} />
                <Route name="course-detail" path="/course-detail" component={CourseDetail} />
                <Route name="login" path="/login" component={LoginForm} />
                <Route path="/" component={App} />
            </Switch>
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>
),document.getElementById('app'));
```

Getting below error :

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Unable to track where exactly the issue is.

Comment: One of your component imports probably isn't correct

Comment: @dentemm thanks for quick reply, I don't see any errors being shown when writing the code on phpstorm editor, but when save the file and see the frontend render on browser I get this error, it shows in editor all imported properly.

Comment: What ever the components that you created which you imported in the code you shared. Make sure all those components class starts with export default class. It shouldn’t be export class

Comment: @hemadri sure will check

Answer (score 41):

I know this may sound silly, but try to check all your imported components with a simple `console.log`:

```
console.log('Provider', Provider);
console.log('ConnectedRouter', ConnectedRouter);
console.log('Route', Route);
console.log('Switch', Switch);
console.log('Home', Home);
console.log('Register', Register);
console.log('CourseManagerDashboard', CourseManagerDashboard);
console.log('CourseDetail', CourseDetail);
console.log('App', App);
console.log('LoginForm', LoginForm);
```

Put this before `ReactDOM.render`, after `const history = createHistory();`

The line with `undefined` in it is causing the problem.

Comment: I have replaced <ConnectedRouter history={history}> with <Router history={history}>, so it wokred fine now, but many of them say to use ConnectedRouter 
Ref: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-redux/9781786462398/53627206-5feb-431c-bf79-c0d0051cd947.xhtml

Comment: If I use version "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8", then I have to import ConnectedRouter without curly braces, but when used latest Alpha version then I can call it as {ConnectedRouter}, but even that gives me some other errors when rendering.

Comment: Please use `connected-react-router` npm package instead of `react-router-redux`. Import it with curly braces: `import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router';`. See the [usage](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router#usage) on the project's GitHub page.

Comment: sure will check. Thanks. @david molnar

Comment: If you have found my answer helpful, please mark it as an answer (see the tick symbol next to the answer's body).

Comment: in my case some imports evaluated to `undefined`, and restarting the development server fixed it

Comment: sometimes you just need someone to slap you right across the face; this was helpful for me :D

Comment: Thank you! You saved me haha.

Answer (score 20):

In my case, the imports were correct. I just had to remove the braces around the imported class name in the imports section

It used to be

`import {DropDownPicker} from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';`

I just had to remove the braces around the `DropDownPicker`

Comment: Thanks!
This issue is so stupid...

Comment: it was struggle for a few days. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the {} (braces) from the component import file.

Answer (score 2):

Check your imports and the components that you have used. Make sure any of them is not completely blank.

Comment: I fixed my problem by fixing the import. I found out by uncommenting blocks of code to find out which one causes the error, then check imports for this block.

Answer (score 0):

This warning can also come from the opposite. I was using react-charts-2 with nextjs

`import { BarChart3 } from "../components/BarChart3";`

Adding curly braces got rid of the error.